# React navigation open openDrawer() not working

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, stack-navigator

This is my navigation codes, I've got a drawer navigator, that contains stacks within, the problem I am having is that I can't use `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` within the stack, navigators to open the drawer but I still can open the drawer by swiping on the screen. my code,

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: AppStack,
    MyAccount: MyAccountStack,
    PointsProfile: PointsProfStack,
    WishList: WishListStack,
    BonusPoint: BonusPoint,
    ContactUs: ContactUs,
    InviteFriend: InviteFriend,
    Terms: Terms,
    SignOut: SignOut
  }
}


const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Home,
    Notification: Notification,
    Suggested: Suggested,
    HomeSearch: HomeSearchV2,
    SearchHist: DishSearchHistory,
    //tab screens
    MealScreen: MealScreenTab,
    SearchScreen: SearchScreenTab,
    CuisineScreen: CuisineScreenTab
})
```

when I console logged `this.props.navigation` within the `AppStack` I found out that the `openDrawer()` function is not provided.
But when I console logged `this.props.navigation` within `ContactUs` which is just a screen, It shows `openDrawer()` function.

Is the way I am writing my navigation wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can refer the code for the navigation drawer.

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import {
      createDrawerNavigator,
      createStackNavigator,
      createAppContainer,
    } from 'react-navigation';
     
    import Screen1 from './pages/Screen1';
    import Screen2 from './pages/Screen2';
    import Screen3 from './pages/Screen3';
     
    class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
      //Structure for the navigatin Drawer
      toggleDrawer = () => {
        //Props to open/close the drawer
        this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
              {/*Donute Button Image */}
              <Image
                source={require('./image/drawer.png')}
                style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
     
    const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      //All the screen from the Screen1 will be indexed here
      First: {
        screen: Screen1,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Demo Screen 1',
          headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
        }),
      },
    });
     
    const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      //All the screen from the Screen2 will be indexed here
      Second: {
        screen: Screen2,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Demo Screen 2',
          headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
        }),
      },
    });
     
    const Screen3_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      //All the screen from the Screen3 will be indexed here
      Third: {
        screen: Screen3,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Demo Screen 3',
          headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
        }),
      },
    });
     
    const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
      //Drawer Options and indexing
      Screen1: {
        //Title
        screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
          drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 1',
        },
      },
      Screen2: {
        //Title
        screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
          drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 2',
        },
      },
      Screen3: {
        //Title
        screen: Screen3_StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
          drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 3',
        },
      },
    });
     
    export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);
```

Have a good day.

Comment: Hi, thanks. but what if i need to use a custom header instead of the default.

Comment: Hello @NaveedSheriffdeen, you can use the `header` inside the `navigationOptions ` and can set your layout in it. Like below.
```navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                header: (props) => (
                    // Your custom header layout component.
                )
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the screen of the drawer is defined, but no definition is associated with the view to be shown. You can configure your own Drawer, you can set draw value.

**example**

```js
class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Home',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
        style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
      />
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    );
  }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'Notifications',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={require('./notif-icon.png')}
        style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
      />
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        title="Go back home"
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
});

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
});

const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
```

Comment: for `Home` I am not passing a screen, I am passing a Stack with the `HomeScreen` as the `initialroute`